# Replace multiple text in Range

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I want to replace multiple text / punctuation marks for example

`","` with `" "`

`"'s"` with `" "`

`,` `'s` are Extra text which I do not need for next step.

`Replace` method can change only one time

Is there any other way to replace multiple text from the following sentence?

"Aabar remains focused on Abu Dhabi’s plans expansion, In Dubai ahead of Expo 2020"

`Replace` works with `,` but `'s` is still there.

```
Sub make_range_replace_string()
Dim R As Range
Dim F As String
Do
    selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
    With selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With
    selection.Find.Execute
    If selection.Find.Found Then
   Set R = ActiveDocument.Range(selection.Range.Start, selection.Range.End)

   F = Replace(R, ",", "") 

   MsgBox F

Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You can nest the `Replace` functions like `F = Replace(Replace(R, ",", "") ,"'s", " ")`.

Comment: @DougGlancy
 `Replace` works with `,` but `'s` is still there. what should I do?

Comment: Create a two-dimensional array with all the replacement-words and iterate through the list with the above posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doug Glancey is correct, just use ’ instead of ' though. 
In other words; use the Replace-function multiple times.

```
Dim F As String

F = "Aabar remains focused on Abu Dhabi’s plans expansion, In Dubai ahead of Expo 2020"
F = Replace(F, ",", " ")
F = Replace(F, "`s", " ")
F = Replace(F, "’s", " ")
F = Replace(F, "'s", " ")
F = Replace(F, Chr(39) & "s", " ")
F = Replace(F, Chr(96) & "s", " ")

MsgBox F
```

Comment: as you notice `'s` is attached to the text, so `Replace(F, "’s", " ")` is not working. There should be another way?

Comment: Strange, I've edited the answer with more variations of the `'s`